# Linear Regulator Operation

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, linear, linear-regulator

I have a linear regulator with three pins. It's identifier is LM7805.
I've taken a look at it's datasheet and it looks unlike linear regulators I've encountered.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Block Diagram]

Is the the op amp circuit included in this schematic?
There are segments of the block diagram I am sure surpass your standard linear regulator with an open op amp and a transistor. What segments of this schematic compose the Thermal Protection? The Safe Operating Area Protection? Other blocks?

Comment: The 7805 is _the_ prototypical linear regulator. You should be able to find explanations of how it works pretty easily online. As for why it looks very different from other ones you've encountered, the 7805 is from an era before high-level block diagrams were the only thing presented in datasheets; this datasheet shows you every transistor instead.

Comment: You need to read this http://www.righto.com/2014/09/reverse-engineering-counterfeit-7805.html and Q14 is for thermal protection.

Comment: @G36 That was a fascinating read, thank you for the link even though it wasn't intended for me!

Comment: Interesting that link shows Q19 and above Q15 max

Comment: Your article was helpful. Some BJTs will operate at varying temperature depending on the current. This is leveraged as a building block to achieve a precise voltage.